# Flume not processing keywords from Twitter source with flume-ng with Hadoop 2.5 cdh5.3

Tags: flume-ng, flume-twitter

I am trying to process some twitter keywords with `MemChannel` and `HDFS`. But `flume-ng` is not showing further progress after `HDFS started` status on the console.

Here are `/etc/flume-ns/conf/flume-env.sh` file contents.

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# If this file is placed at FLUME_CONF_DIR/flume-env.sh, it will be sourced during Flume startup.
# Environment variables can be set here.

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera

# Give Flume more memory and pre-allocate, enable remote monitoring via JMX
# export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms100m -Xmx2000m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
# Note that the Flume conf directory is always included in the classpath.
#FLUME_CLASSPATH=""
```

Here are the twitter configuration file contents.

```
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

#TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = hadoop, big data, analytics, bigdata, cloudera, data science, data scientist, business intelligence, mapreduce, data warehouse, data warehousing, mahout, hbase, nosql, newsql, businessintelligence, cloudcomputing

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://uat.cloudera:8020/user/root/flume/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

I am running below command on centOs console.

```
flume-ng agent -c /etc/flume-ng/conf -f /etc/flume-ng/conf/twitter.conf -n TwitterAgent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

When I run the command here is the output.

```
Info: Sourcing environment configuration script /etc/flume-ng/conf/flume-env.sh
Info: Including Hadoop libraries found via (/usr/bin/hadoop) for HDFS access
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar from classpath
Info: Including HBASE libraries found via (/usr/bin/hbase) for HBASE access
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar from classpath
+ exec /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -cp r/lib/flume-ng/../search/lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/flume-ng/../search/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/flume-ng/../search/lib/xmpcore-5.1.2.jar:/usr/lib/flume-ng/../search/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/flume-ng/../search/lib/zookeeper.jar' -Djava.library.path=:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native org.apache.flume.node.Application -f /etc/flume-ng/conf/farrukh.conf -n TwitterAgent
2015-09-24 12:05:38,876 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.start(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:61)] Configuration provider starting
2015-09-24 12:05:38,885 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:133)] Reloading configuration file:/etc/flume-ng/conf/farrukh.conf
2015-09-24 12:05:38,896 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1017)] Processing:HDFS
2015-09-24 12:05:38,896 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1017)] Processing:HDFS
2015-09-24 12:05:38,897 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1017)] Processing:HDFS
2015-09-24 12:05:38,897 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:931)] Added sinks: HDFS Agent: TwitterAgent
2015-09-24 12:05:38,897 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1017)] Processing:HDFS
2015-09-24 12:05:38,897 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1017)] Processing:HDFS
2015-09-24 12:05:38,897 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1017)] Processing:HDFS
2015-09-24 12:05:38,897 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1017)] Processing:HDFS
2015-09-24 12:05:38,898 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1017)] Processing:HDFS
2015-09-24 12:05:38,911 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.validateSources(FlumeConfiguration.java:508)] Agent configuration for 'TwitterAgent' has no sources.
2015-09-24 12:05:38,919 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:141)] Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [TwitterAgent]
2015-09-24 12:05:38,920 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadChannels(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:145)] Creating channels
2015-09-24 12:05:38,939 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.DefaultChannelFactory.create(DefaultChannelFactory.java:42)] Creating instance of channel MemChannel type memory
2015-09-24 12:05:38,957 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadChannels(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:200)] Created channel MemChannel
2015-09-24 12:05:38,963 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.create(DefaultSinkFactory.java:42)] Creating instance of sink: HDFS, type: hdfs
2015-09-24 12:05:40,019 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.authenticate(HDFSEventSink.java:559)] Hadoop Security enabled: false
2015-09-24 12:05:40,022 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:114)] Channel MemChannel connected to [HDFS]
2015-09-24 12:05:40,031 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:138)] Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{HDFS=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@3c1cefaa counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{MemChannel=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: MemChannel}} }
2015-09-24 12:05:40,040 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:145)] Starting Channel MemChannel
2015-09-24 12:05:40,218 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:120)] Monitored counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: MemChannel: Successfully registered new MBean.
2015-09-24 12:05:40,218 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:96)] Component type: CHANNEL, name: MemChannel started
2015-09-24 12:05:40,219 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:173)] Starting Sink HDFS
2015-09-24 12:05:40,221 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:120)] Monitored counter group for type: SINK, name: HDFS: Successfully registered new MBean.
2015-09-24 12:05:40,221 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:96)] Component type: SINK, name: HDFS started
```

Here is detail of my computer environment.

JDK

```
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

OS

```
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
cat: /etc/lsb-release.d: Is a directory
cpe:/o:centos:linux:6:GA
```

Flume-ng

```
Flume 1.5.0-cdh5.3.0
Source code repository: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/flume.git
Revision: cc2139f386f7fccc9a6e105e2026228af58c6e9f
Compiled by jenkins on Tue Dec 16 20:25:18 PST 2014
From source with checksum 0b02653a07c9e96af03ce2189b8d51c3
```

Hadoop

```
Hadoop 2.5.0-cdh5.3.0
Subversion http://github.com/cloudera/hadoop -r f19097cda2536da1df41ff6713556c8f7284174d
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-12-17T03:05Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 9c4267e6915cf5bbd4c6e08be54d54e0
This command was run using /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.5.0-cdh5.3.0.jar
```

Here is output of hdfs report command.

```
Configured Capacity: 20506943488 (19.10 GB)
Present Capacity: 20506943488 (19.10 GB)
DFS Remaining: 20057721155 (18.68 GB)
DFS Used: 449222333 (428.41 MB)
DFS Used%: 2.19%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 127.0.0.1:50010 (uat.cloudera)
Hostname: uat.cloudera
Rack: /default
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 20506943488 (19.10 GB)
DFS Used: 449222333 (428.41 MB)
Non DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 20057721155 (18.68 GB)
DFS Used%: 2.19%
DFS Remaining%: 97.81%
Configured Cache Capacity: 4294967296 (4 GB)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 4294967296 (4 GB)
Cache Used%: 0.00%
Cache Remaining%: 100.00%
Xceivers: 6
Last contact: Thu Sep 25 12:09:42 PDT 2015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing ".sources" property of the agent. How can Flume-ng work without knowing the source? You are missing following line.

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
```

See `source`, `channel` and `sink` relationship diagram.
[image]

To see more detail, see following link:
https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html

Always remember there are mainly three things in flume configuration file.( sources, channels, sinks ). First three lines are setting these three properties.

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
```

Rest of the configuration file is setting detailed properties of these three main things (`sources`, `channels`, `sinks`).

Check below corrected configuration file contents.

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

#TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxxxx

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = hadoop, big data, analytics, bigdata, cloudera, data science, data scientiest, business intelligence, mapreduce, data warehouse, data warehousing, mahout, hbase, nosql, newsql, businessintelligence, cloudcomputing

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://uat.cloudera:8020/user/root/flume/
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 10
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 10
```

Other than setting `sources` property, I have also changed the below properties, so that we can quickly see the results on hdfs as temp files.

```
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 10
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 10
```

Copy the contents and save in any configuration file e.g sample.conf in /etc/flume-ng/conf/ folder and then use below command.

```
flume-ng agent -c /etc/flume-ng/conf -f /etc/flume-ng/conf/sample.conf -n TwitterAgent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

After HDFS Started status, it should show processing message like this.

```
2015-09-25 13:44:18,045 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-4) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.start(TwitterSource.java:139)] Twitter source Twitter started.
2015-09-25 13:44:18,045 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[initializing]) [INFO - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] Establishing connection.
2015-09-25 13:44:19,931 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [INFO - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] Connection established.
2015-09-25 13:44:19,931 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [INFO - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] Receiving status stream.
2015-09-25 13:44:20,283 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSDataStream.configure(HDFSDataStream.java:58)] Serializer = TEXT, UseRawLocalFileSystem = false
2015-09-25 13:44:20,557 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.open(BucketWriter.java:261)] Creating hdfs://uat.cloudera:8020/user/root/flume/FlumeData.1443213860284.tmp
2015-09-25 13:44:22,435 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:178)] Processed 100 docs
2015-09-25 13:44:25,383 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:178)] Processed 200 docs
2015-09-25 13:44:28,178 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:178)] Processed 300 docs
2015-09-25 13:44:30,505 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.close(BucketWriter.java:413)] Closing hdfs://uat.cloudera:8020/user/root/flume/FlumeData.1443213860284.tmp
2015-09-25 13:44:30,506 (hdfs-HDFS-call-runner-2) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$3.call(BucketWriter.java:339)] Close tries incremented
2015-09-25 13:44:30,526 (hdfs-HDFS-call-runner-3) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$8.call(BucketWriter.java:673)] Renaming hdfs://uat.cloudera:8020/user/root/flume/FlumeData.1443213860284.tmp to hdfs://uat.cloudera:8020/user/root/flume/FlumeData.1443213860284
2015-09-25 13:44:30,607 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.open(BucketWriter.java:261)] Creating hdfs://uat.cloudera:8020/user/root/flume/FlumeData.1443213860285.tmp
2015-09-25 13:44:31,157 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:178)] Processed 400 docs
2015-09-25 13:44:33,330 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:178)] Processed 500 docs
2015-09-25 13:44:36,131 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:178)] Processed 600 docs
2015-09-25 13:44:38,298 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:178)] Processed 700 docs
2015-09-25 13:44:40,465 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:178)] Processed 800 docs
2015-09-25 13:44:41,158 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.close(BucketWriter.java:413)] Closing hdfs://uat.cloudera:8020/user/root/flume/FlumeData.1443213860285.tmp
2015-09-25 13:44:41,158 (hdfs-HDFS-call-runner-6) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$3.call(BucketWriter.java:339)] Close tries incremented
2015-09-25 13:44:41,166 (hdfs-HDFS-call-runner-7) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$8.call(BucketWriter.java:673)] Renaming hdfs://uat.cloudera:8020/user/root/flume/FlumeData.1443213860285.tmp to hdfs://uat.cloudera:8020/user/root/flume/FlumeData.1443213860285
2015-09-25 13:44:41,230 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.open(BucketWriter.java:261)] Creating hdfs://uat.cloudera:8020/user/root/flume/FlumeData.1443213860286.tmp
2015-09-25 13:44:43,238 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:178)] Processed 900 docs
2015-09-25 13:44:46,118 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:178)] Processed 1,000 docs
2015-09-25 13:44:46,118 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.logStats(TwitterSource.java:300)] Total docs indexed: 1,000, total skipped docs: 0
2015-09-25 13:44:46,118 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.logStats(TwitterSource.java:302)]     35 docs/second
2015-09-25 13:44:46,118 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.logStats(TwitterSource.java:304)] Run took 28 seconds and processed:
2015-09-25 13:44:46,118 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.logStats(TwitterSource.java:306)]     0.009 MB/sec sent to index
2015-09-25 13:44:46,119 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.logStats(TwitterSource.java:308)]     0.255 MB text sent to index
2015-09-25 13:44:46,119 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.logStats(TwitterSource.java:310)] There were 0 exceptions ignored:
^C2015-09-25 13:44:46,666 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor.stop(LifecycleSupervisor.java:79)] Stopping lifecycle supervisor 10
2015-09-25 13:44:46,673 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.stop(TwitterSource.java:150)] Twitter source Twitter stopping...
```

Let me know if your issue is still now resolved.

Comment: Also make sure that `hdfs://uat.cloudera:8020/user/root/flume/` path is valid.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detail response as well.