# Apache Flume stuck with Twitter agent

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-16.04, flume-twitter

When I try to stream Twitter data with Apache Flume with this command

```
bin/flume- agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/twitter.conf
Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent
```

The console is stuck here and flume didn't stream data in the HDFS system:

[image]

Comment: I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790148/flume-not-processing-keywords-from-twitter-source-with-flume-ng-with-hadoop-2-5